# pyqt5 cx_freeze compilation

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyqt5

i try to make exe with cx_freeze, when compiling i get this messages: http://wklej.org/id/1457081/
and when i run my output file i get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0YfD.png
my setup is simple:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit'
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('start.pyw', base=base)
]

setup(name='simple_PyQt5',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze PyQt5 script',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

error from link i get every time when i make some pyqt5 app, even simple
I don't really know how i should write this setup file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a current issue with Python 3.4.1 + PyQt5.

Please see this [bug](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/81/python-34-venv-importlib-attributeerror) report on cx_freeze for more info.

The suggestion is that you could build cx_freeze from source which would then work just fine.

The alternative would be to go back to Python 3.3.5 for the time being unless you need anything that Python 3.4.1 introduced.

Comment: thank you, on bug report page is link to cx_freeze build which work fine